# Using datetime.now gives datetime.datetime error

Tags: python, datetime

so i've been on the python language making stuff. I encounter some error which is not so understandable:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

(I think) this is the code that cause it:

```py
def brew():
    # Get UTC time
    curr_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    # Slice it
    curr_dt = curr_dt[0:19]
    # Print
    print(curr_dt)
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to get the date and time in `2022-01-04 14:25:10.860837+00:00` by slicing it. Is there a solution of how to get rid of error or even comes with more easy and/or practical ways? Thank You for Your time.

Comment: you have a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object `curr_dt` - you can't subscript that (the `[0:19]` part). Convert to string first, e.g. `datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(' ')[:19]`.

Comment: Maybe you want [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) ?

Comment: Use `datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` or `str(datetime.now(timezone.utc))[:19]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def brew():
    # curr_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    curr_dt = str(datetime.now(timezone.utc))[:19]
    print(curr_dt)
```

Output:

```
>>> brew()
'2022-01-04 14:35:04'
```